# Allocate array with pointers to struct C and return that array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return, malloc

I need to allocate an  k-sized array with pointers to a struct within a function and return that array back to main .

My struct is:

```
typedef struct record
{
   /*Data*/
}record;
```

My function:

```
record** function(int k)
{
     record** array;
     array = (record*)malloc(sizeof(record *) * k); 

     /* fulfill array 
     array[1] = &record1 ; /* For example*/
     */

     return array;
}
```

In main:

```
int main(void)
{
   record** arr ;
   arr = function(5);
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      print(array[i]); /*iterate the array*/
   }
 }
```

The problem is that i am getting segmentation faults when trying to print my arr after returning it

Comment: And what is your actual question? That is, what specifically is preventing you from doing what you want to do? Showing the code is the right thing to do but you also need to ask a *specific* question in reference to that code.

Comment: @kaylum i edited the question. sorry i am really tired. does anything seem wrong to my piece of code ?

Comment: Yes, it's obvious. The array contents are uninitalised. That is, `array[i]` values are all junk.

Comment: You've allocated an array of pointers to structures and not an array of structures. You need to lose one star.  If you had an array of `int`, you'd use `int *`; if you want an array of 'record `, you use `record *`.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler error/warning messages

Answer (score 0):

seg fault in this situation is because you're trying to dereference a NULL memory address.

Firstly, you should check if a piece of data is NULL or not, then dereference it... You broke the first rule of C pointers.

Secondly, don't typecast an malloc'd pointer.

typecast is only necessary when changing or identifying a certain byte size...

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to reference a previously allocated set of `records` and assign a pointer to your `array` in `function`. While you can do that, you must either pass the existing set of records as a parameter to `function`, allocate and fill the set in `function`, or the records must be readable within `function` (e.g. a global, etc..). (You cannot assign the address of a local variable in `function` to `array` as the function stack for `function` is destroyed on its return.)

In the example below, an array of `int` is passed to `function` to fill the `record.data` members. If you were passing an array of `record` instead, you would eliminate allocating for the `struct` itself as you could assign the address to the pointers you first allocate. Look it over and let me know if you have questions, or if you need to see some other form of an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int data;
} record;

record **function (int *thedata, int k)
{
    record **array = malloc (k * sizeof *array); /* allocate pointers */
    if (array && thedata)
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            array[i] = malloc (sizeof **array);  /* allocate struct */
            array[i]->data = thedata[i];
        }

    return array;
}

int main (void) {

    record **arr = NULL;
    int a[] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 },
        n   = sizeof a/sizeof *a;

    if ((arr = function (a, n))) {  /* validate function return */
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf (" arr[%d] : %d\n", i, arr[i]->data);
            free (arr[i]);
        }
        free (arr); /* free allocated pointers */
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: function returned NULL.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/p2p2i
 arr[0] : 5
 arr[1] : 10
 arr[2] : 15
 arr[3] : 20
 arr[4] : 25
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an uninitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice, e.g.:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/p2p2i
==6703== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6703== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6703== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6703== Command: ./bin/p2p2i
==6703==
 arr[0] : 5
 arr[1] : 10
 arr[2] : 15
 arr[3] : 20
 arr[4] : 25
==6703==
==6703== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6703==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6703==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 60 bytes allocated
==6703==
==6703== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6703==
==6703== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6703== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*. (although note: some OS's do not provide adequate memeory exclusion files (*the file that excludes system and OS memory from being reported as in use*) which will cause `valgrind` to report that some memory has not yet been freed (despite the fact you have done your job and freed al blocks you allocoted and under your control.)

Answer (score -1):

Little mistake over here :

array = (record**)malloc(sizeof(record *) * k);

Stupid me

Comment: What is the correct code supposed to be? If you provide an answer please make it clear. You can make it clear by providing the correct code.